# R not removing terms when doing MAM

Tags: r, glm

I want to do a MAM, but I'm having difficulty in removing some terms:

```
 full.model<-glm(SSB_sq~Veg_height+Bare+Common+Birds_Foot+Average_March+Average_April+
Average_May+Average_June15+Average_June20+Average_June25+Average_July15
+Average_July20+Average_July25,family="poisson") 
summary(full.model)
```

I believe I have to remove these terms to start the MAM like so:

```
  model1<-update(full.model,~.-Veg_height:Bare:Common:Birds_Foot:Average_March
:Average_April:Average_May:Average_June15:Average_June20:Average_June25:
Average_July15:Average_July20:Average_July25,family="poisson")
summary(model1)
anova(model1,full.model,test="Chi")
```

But I get this output:

```
anova(model1,full.model,test="Chi")
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: SSB_sq ~ Veg_height + Bare + Common + Birds_Foot + Average_March + 
    Average_April + Average_May + Average_June15 + Average_June20 + 
    Average_June25 + Average_July15 + Average_July20 + Average_July25
Model 2: SSB_sq ~ Veg_height + Bare + Common + Birds_Foot + Average_March + 
    Average_April + Average_May + Average_June15 + Average_June20 + 
    Average_June25 + Average_July15 + Average_July20 + Average_July25
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance P(>|Chi|)
1       213     237.87                      
2       213     237.87  0        0
```

I've tried putting plus signs in model1 instead of colons, as I was clutching at straws when reading my notes but the same thing happens.

Why are both my models the same? I've tried searching on Google but I'm not very good at the terminology so my searches aren't bringing up much.

Comment: The colon term ":" in a formula designates an interaction effect. See ?formula. Could you show us the call for model1 after you've updated... `model1$call`?

Comment: OK, so ":" and * designate interactions? I'm not interested in the interactions at the moment hence me using "+", so I obviously need to change my colons to something else in model1? I'm embarrassed to say I don't understand what you're asking in model1$call too. I'm very sorry!

Comment: I worked out what you meant, dozy moment! `> model1$call glm(formula = SSB_sq ~ Veg_height + Bare + Common + Birds_Foot + Average_March + Average_April + Average_May + Average_June15 + Average_June20 + Average_June25 + Average_July15 + Average_July20 + Average_July25, family = "poisson")`

Comment: And MAM means what, exactly? "Minimal, adequate model"?

Comment: Yes, MAM is minimal adequate model, although some papers have it as minimum adequate model.

Comment: OK - presumed as much, I also assume you want a null model with only an intercept as you tried to remove all the variable with your `update()` call. If this is correct, then see my Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read your intention correctly, are you trying to fit a null model with no terms in it? If so, a simpler way is just to use the `SSB_sq ~ 1` as the formula, meaning a model with only an intercept.

```
fit <- lm(sr ~ ., data = LifeCycleSavings)
fit0 <- lm(sr ~ 1, data = LifeCycleSavings)
## or via an update:
fit01 <- update(fit, . ~ 1)
```

Which gives, for example:

```
> anova(fit)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: sr
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
pop15      1 204.12 204.118 14.1157 0.0004922 ***
pop75      1  53.34  53.343  3.6889 0.0611255 .  
dpi        1  12.40  12.401  0.8576 0.3593551    
ddpi       1  63.05  63.054  4.3605 0.0424711 *  
Residuals 45 650.71  14.460                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 
> anova(fit, fit0)
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: sr ~ pop15 + pop75 + dpi + ddpi
Model 2: sr ~ 1
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F    Pr(>F)    
1     45 650.71                                  
2     49 983.63 -4   -332.92 5.7557 0.0007904 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

An explanation of the formulae I use:

- The first model used the shortcut `.`, which means all remaining variables in argument `data` (in my model it meant all variables in `LifeCycleSavings` on the RHS of the formula, except for `sr` which is already on the LHS).
- In the second model (`fit0`), we only include `1` on the RHS of the formula. In R, `1` means an intercept, so `sr ~ 1` means fit an intercept-only model. By default, an intercept is assumed, hence we did not need `1` when specifying the first model `fit`.
- If you want to suppress an intercept, add `- 1` or `+ 0` to your formula.

For your data, the first model would be:

```
full.model <- glm(SSB_sq ~ ., data = FOO, family = "poisson")
```

where `FOO` is the data frame holding your variables - you are using a data frame, aren't you? The null, intercept-only model would be specified using one of:

```
null.model <- glm(SSB_sq ~ 1, data = FOO, family = "poisson")
```

or

```
null.model <- update(full.model, . ~ 1)
```

Comment: Wow, I've never seen anything like this in my notes! How would my data fit into this? Am I just replacing LifeCycleSavings?

Comment: Well I figured it out and got it to work up until the anova(fit,fit0) part where it told me `Error in anova.lmlist(object, ...) : models were not all fitted to the same size of dataset`

Comment: @Gem `LifeCycleSavings` is a data frame containing the variables used ot fit the model. You should replace it with your data frame containing the variables you mention. Also note that I used `lm()` but these are general concepts used with many R modelling functions including `glm()`

Comment: @Gem do you have missing data in one or more of the covariates used to fit the full model? R will drop observations that have missing data, which might explain the error. If you have a recent R (>= 2.13.0) then try running `nobs(FOO)` on each of your models (where `FOO` is replaced by one of your model objects).

Comment: I do have missing values, but they've been replaced with na values, so tried:`Full.clean<- na.omit(Full)
> detach(Full)
> attach(Full.clean)` but then when I ran your coding, although it worked (thank you!), it was including my response variables too. I just don't understand why my original methods, which is how I've been taught to do MAM isn't working! :(

Comment: Do **not** attach! That is what the `data` argument in the formula methods are for. Do `m1 <- glm(SSB_sq ~ ., data = Full.clean, family = "poisson")` and `m0 <- glm(SSB_sq ~ 1, data = Full.clean, family = "poisson")` to fit the full and the intercept-only models. R will drop entire rows that have any `NA` observations for variables in them; `NA` is how R records missingness.

Comment: What does "it was including my response variables too" mean? what is "it"? The reason your original version didn't work was because there is no variable named `Veg_height:Bare:Common:....` which is what you asked R to remove. It you'd done `update(full.model, . ~ . - Veg_height - Bare - Common)` etc, using `-` not `:` between the variables it would have done what you wanted. You seem to be flailing in the dark somewhat here. Can I suggest you take a break, ignore your notes and read a proper guide to modelling with R - see any of the books or contributed documentation on the R webiste.

Comment: @GavinSimpson, this is a great answer to a related question of Gem's, but I don't think that it actually answers her question. A minimal adequate model should be testing the effect of removing each predictor variable. Your code looks like it compares the full model to a null model, but there are no intermediate models in between. Does that make sense? Does anyone happen to have advice about this??

Comment: @Atticus29 As I said at the time, it wasn't exactly clear what *was* wanted. Looking again, it is clear that the OP fitted a model with no interactions and then tried to remove them - at least that is what it shows now, and I mention this in the comment above. I don't fully agree with your definition of a MAM nor the concept of a MAM. Why should there be only one model for example? Any stepwise selection will be biased; if you are interested in prediction, I'd try one of the shrinkage methods such as the Lasso or Elastic net in package **glmnet**